# Gunicorn, обслуживающй VPS, не видит CSS админки

Tags: django, сервер, веб-сервер, vps, gunicorn

Всем здравствуйте!

Ранее я никогда не занимался настройкой и обслуживанием `VPS`. Недавно запустил проект - выбрал `gunicorn` в силу простоты настройки. Все работает хорошо, но вот стили в админке не подгружаются. Сначала, не понимая, в чем причина, пытался установить `grappelli` - безуспешно. После я раскопал информацию, что `gunicorn` вообще не умеет подгружать стили админки.

Можно ли как-то заставить `gunicorn` корректно решать эту задачу без негативных последствий для проекта? Если нет, то что лучше использовать вместо него?

Буду благодарен за любой ответ

Answer (score 1):

При работе под сервером `gunicorn` статические файлы (изображения и css-стили) не будут отображаться: этот сервер работает только с динамическими запросами.

Для работы со статическими файлами можно воспользоваться `nginx`, он отвечает за перенаправление HTTP - запросов:

- если нужно отдать статический файл или перенаправить запрос — это
  поручается `nginx`;
- если нужно выполнить какие-то логические задачи —
  это возьмёт на себя WSGI-сервер `gunicorn`.

[хороший туториал по настройке](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru)

Comment: понял, спасибо!